# Finding parameters in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

For the following block design I am trying to determine if the design is a BIBD and if so, determine its parameters $v, b ,r, k,$ and $\lambda$. $$V = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$$ blocks: $\{a,b,c,d\}, \{a,c,d,e\}, \{a,b,d,e\}, \{ a,b,c,e\}, \{ b,c,d,e\}$

Relevant formulas: $bk=vr$ and $\lambda(v-1)=r(k-1)$

the parameter $k$ represents the number of elements in each block, so clearly $k = 4$

**But how do I proceed to find the other parameters? And is this even a BIBD?**

Comment: I stands for "incomplete". This is a "complete" design, consisting of **all** subsets of a given size of the set of points.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown does this mean that it is not a BIBD?